# gradle buildscripts and Heroku

Tags: heroku, gradle

If i'd like to use a Steve Saliman's gradle-cobertura-plugin inside my gradle build. Will I need to use a custom buildpack to deploy to Heroku.com? I receive the following error when Heroku tries to run my build. Note, that the very same build works great when I run it locally.

```
Repository git@heroku.com:myproject.git

pre-receive hook declined
Fetching repository, done.

-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.7... done
-----> Building Gradle app...
       WARNING: The Gradle buildpack is currently in Beta.
-----> executing gradle -I /app/tmp/buildpacks/gradle/opt/init.gradle stage
       Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/saliman/gradle-cobertura-    plugin/2.2.2/gradle-cobertura-plugin-2.2.2.pom
   Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.0.6/groovy-all-2.0.6.pom
   Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/saliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin/2.2.2/gradle-cobertura-plugin-2.2.2.jar
   Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.0.6/groovy-all-2.0.6.jar

   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * Where:
   Build file '/tmp/build_2be-36-41-8-91a50/build.gradle' line: 10

   * What went wrong:
   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'build_346f'.
   Cause: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention.create() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated) values: [cobertura, class net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.CoberturaExtension, root project 'build_4dyre0']
   Possible solutions: iterator()

   * Try:
   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

   BUILD FAILED

   Total time: 7.539 secs
 !     Failed to build app

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Gradle app
```

here is the part of my build that introduces the plugin - and the error:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.2.2"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'cobertura'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it turns out, heroku have a pretty old standard Gradle buildpack. I had to change it with one that makes use of a newer version of my favourite build tool, Gradle.

BUILDPACK_URL: https://github.com/krro/heroku-buildpack-gradle.git

I did so by setting the heroku config propery above.

more about this topic: http://www.wiredforcode.com/blog/2014/02/11/deploy-to-heroku-with-gradle

Comment: could you post an example of your whole gradle file please?